# Is possible to have a widget that doesnt scroll in a QScrollArea?

Tags: c++, qt

Given this example:

Suppose **A** and **B** are `QWidgets`

[image: designer_dEUJfPmxui.png]

Is it possible to keep everything starting from **B** static when the `QScrollArea` widget is scrolled?

The  `QScrollArea` occupies the entire GUI, **B** is inside it to let the **vertical** `ScrollBar`  closer to the right border of the GUI, or it would look like this:

[image: 1fc36ead-1b65-4f0f-8f9a-95c08eb5881f-image.png]

What I can do in this case?

Comment: If `B`'s sole purpose is to push the vertical scroll bar to the right, I'd suggest getting rid of B and finding another way to accomplish that.  Trying to get a QScrollArea to not scroll some of the widgets that are within its scrollable area is going to be an exercise in frustration.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner `If B's sole purpose is to push the vertical scroll bar to the right` No, `B` is a widget containing few other widgets that i would like that they not get scrolled together with the QScrollArea.

Comment: I think you will need to move B to outside of the QScrollArea then.

Comment: The purpose of a scroll area is to scroll the things it contains. Why do you have something in the scroll area when that something is supposed to not scroll? (I mean "in" in the logical sense of the "something" being a child (or descendant) widget of the scroll area, not "in" in the visual sense of the something merely being drawn in the same part of the screen as the scroll area.)

Comment: `Why do you have something in the scroll area when that something is supposed to not scroll?` Isnt this explained in the question?

Comment: With the graphical widget designer, it's not possible to have overlapping widgets in layouts. You can do this with code (`QGridLayout` supports this, or you can use "manual layout" by overriding resize event.

Comment: Also, if the widget is in the scroll area, it will scroll. It needs to be on top of the scroll area.

Comment: @Raja *"Isnt this explained in the question?"* -- I see an attempt to explain it, but I'm having trouble parsing the sentence structure. My guess is that the reason is weak, so putting `B` inside the scroll area should be relegated to something that was tried rather than being a requirement.

Comment: To put it another way, I think you have a goal X and you think your `B` should achieve the goal, but you ran into trouble. Instead of asking about X, you asked about `B`. Also known as [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), the [bane of help desks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You have to make use of the scrollbar being a widget of its own.

Here is the method:

1. Change your window in Qt Designer to be: spacer, `QScrollArea` (that will contain widget A), spacer, widget B, spacer; everything is in a `QGridLayout` (or `QHBoxLayout` but please read until the end).
   It is because widget B is outside the scroll area that it will not move during scrolling.
2. In your widget constructor, after `ui->setupUi();` reparent and move the vertical scrollbar of your `QScrollArea` with these lines of code:

   ```
   scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setParent(w);
   layout->addWidget(sa->verticalScrollBar()); //Adds the scrollbar to the right of the layout.
   ```

Note about the margins:
Obviously, you can easily push the scrollbar to the very right of your window by setting the layout right margin to 0.
If you also want it to cover the entire height of your window, while keeping some space between the other widgets and the window's border, that is where a `QHBoxLayout` will not suffice and you need a `QGridLayout` instead, set its top and bottom margin to `0` and add spacers (fixed size) to obtain the same visual result.

The C++ code for such a window would be:

```
QWidget* widget = new QWidget();
QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(widget);
layout->setSpacing(0);
layout->setContentsMargins(9, 0, 0, 0);
widget->setLayout(layout);

QScrollArea* scrollArea = new QScrollArea(widget);
scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
QWidget* widgetB = new QLabel("Widget B", widget);
//Creates the spacer that will "simulate" the top and bottom margins
QSpacerItem* topSpacer = new QSpacerItem(0, 9, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Fixed),
    * bottomSpacer = new QSpacerItem(0, 9, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Fixed);

layout->addItem(topSpacer, 0, 0);
layout->addWidget(scrollArea, 1, 0);
layout->addItem(bottomSpacer, 2, 0);
layout->addWidget(widgetB, 1, 1);

//Moves the scrollbar outside the scroll area
scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setParent(widget);
layout->addWidget(scrollArea->verticalScrollBar(), 0, 2, 3, 1);

QLabel* innerLabel = new QLabel("Some big label to force the scrolling");
scrollArea->setWidget(innerLabel);
innerLabel->setMinimumHeight(500);

widget->show();
```